# Retrieve user posts and friends post

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have four eloquent models for four tables; Users, Profiles, Habs, Followers.
I am trying to retrieve all user posts and posts of users a user follower.
My tables looked like this;

**Habs**

- id
- user_id
- hab
- created_at
- updated_at

**Users**

- id
- username
- email
- created_at
- updated_at

**Profiles**

- id
- user_id
- name
- avatar
- created_at
- updated_at

**Followers**

- id
- follower_id
- following_id
- created_at
- updated_at

  I have set up the relationships in models. How do use the Eloquent to select user posts and posts of users the user follows.

Comment: Is the `Habs` table the posts table?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you can start with something like this:

```
class Users extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Profile');
    }

    public function followers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Follower', 'follower_id', 'id');
    }

    public function following()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Follower', 'following_id', 'id');
    }

}

class Hab extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'habs';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}

class Follower extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'followers';

}

class Profile extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'profiles';

}
```

And you should be able to:

Select a user normally

```
$user = User::find(1);
```

Get its Habs

```
$habs = $user->habs;
```

Get its followers

```
$followers = $user->followers;
```

Get who are following him/her

```
$following = $user->following;
```

Get all habs of their Followers

```
foreach($user->followers as $follower)
{

    $followerEmail = $follower->email;
    $followerName = $follower->profile->name;
    $followerHabs = $follower->habs;

}
```

Get all habs from people he/she is following

```
foreach($user->following as $following)
{

    $followingEmail = $following->email;
    $followingName = $following->profile->name;
    $followingHabs = $following->habs;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for `HasManyThrough`. It allows you to query for distant relations.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set relations on Users model only

```
// Users Model
public function followings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'Users',
        'followers', // Assuming this is the table name
        'follower_id',
        'following_id'
    );
}

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Habs');
}
```

Then to get user's posts

```
$posts = User::with('posts')->find(1)->posts;
```

And to get posts the following users

```
$following_users = User::find(1)->followings()->with('posts')->get();
```